# REGEX Search and keep specific characters

Tags: regex

I have hundreds of References in the following format

```
HCVSAM0123BK
c35UNI0321RS
scruni0321
```

XXXXXX ZZZZ WW
6 characters 4 digits 2 characters

I want to keep the 4 digits after the first 6 characters, but in some cases it doesn't have the last 2 characters

My goal is to get only ZZZZ (the 4 digits)

ex: from HCVSAM0123BK to 0123

Thank You

Comment: Hi, this needs a bit more info to be considered a good question. What are you using for the search and replace? What is your wanted output on this example? Where is your attempt failing?

Comment: Be specific in what you want to achieve, and make sure that you rephrase your question to make it educating for other people as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do match the following:

`^\w{6}(\d+)(\w{2})?$`

and the first captured group `\1` is what you want.

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qT0lY8

Answer to udpated question:

`^(?!\d+$)\w{6}(\d+)(\w{2})?$`

`(?!\d+$)` is a negative look ahead, that will fail the match if the line is only digits, and `\w` stands for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I avoid the expression to detect if I have a string with numbers. example: in the same document I also have 5600499301223 but i dont want it to replace in this

Comment: @sshashank124: See my example: `\n\n\nabcd1234` would return a match as the second `\n` is, indeed, at the beginning of its line.

Comment: @Robin, Ah I see. I am slightly busy right now. Please feel free to add to my answer as you deem appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: @sshashank124: I tried to keep the spirit of your answer, added a negative lookahead to avoid digit-only lines (`[a-zA-Z]` and `[^\d]` were both failing on `c35UNI0321RS`)

Answer (score 1):

search : `^.{6}(.{4}).*`

and replace with : `\1`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/kZ7dS8

output :

```
0123 
0321 
0321
```

**using branch reset :**

search : `(?|.*(\d{4}).*)`

and replace with : `\1`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I avoid the expression to detect if I have a string with numbers. example: in the same document I also have 5600499301223 but i dont want it to replace in this